# Finite subquotients of R. Thompson's group $F$

Tags: gr.group-theory

Recall R. Thompson's group $F$ acting on the interval $[0,1]$: it consists of piecewise linear oriented maps with slopes a power of $2$ and dyadic breakpoints.

Is every finite subquotient (= quotient of a subgroup) soluble?

[my money is on "yes". Finite quotients of $F$ itself are abelian. I know subgroups of $F$ that are made of copies of $F$ and of soluble groups, but nothing more exotic.]

Comment: There are very exotic subgroups of $F$. I do not know their finite quotients.

Comment: @MarkSapir do you have a reference for "exotic" subgroups of $F$?

Comment: I'm aware of a rich collection of f.g. subgroups, see http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~justin/Ftp/complexity_subgrp_F.pdf but they're all elementary amenable.

Comment: @YCor: See papers by Brin (alone and with others) and papers by Golan (alone and with me).

Comment: @grok: Yes, all known subgroups of $F$ are either elementary amenable or contains a copy of $F$. But all finite groups are elementary amenable, so it does not answer your question.

Comment: @MarkSapir: It seems to me that something much stronger is true: all known subgroups of $F$ are obtained from $F$ and $\mathbb Z$ using elementary operations.