# Composition factors in subgroups of R. Thomspon's group $F$

Tags: gr.group-theory

Recall Thompson's group $F$, acting by piecewise-affine homeomorphisms on the interval. I wish to make the following conjectures on *all* subgroups of $F$, which originate from [this question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338294/finite-subquotients-of-r-thompsons-group-f).

Recall also that, for a group $H$, a *composition series* is a family of subgroups $(H_\alpha)$ indexed by ordinals, with $H_0=H$ and $H_{\alpha+1}\triangleleft H_\alpha$ with $H_\alpha/H_{\alpha+1}$ simple and $H_\lambda=\bigcap_{\alpha<\lambda}H_\alpha$ for limit ordinals $\lambda$.

**Conjecture 1.** Every subgroup of $F$ admits a composition series.

**Conjecture 2.** In every such composition series, all composition factors are $C_p$ or $F'$.

I know that there are lots of complicated subgroups of $F$, see e.g. [arXiv:1711.10998](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10998), but all these subgroups seem to satisfy the conjecture.

Question: is any of this reasonable for the $F$ experts out there?

Comment: You mean $H_\lambda = \bigcap_{\alpha<\lambda} H_\alpha$ for limit ordinals, right?

Comment: "*Recall that a composition series is...*": is this in any way standard? Anyway, assuming that the definition is fixed with $\bigcap$ in the limit case, Conjecture 1 is equivalent to "*Every nontrivial subgroup of $F$ has a simple quotient*". The latter is true for finitely generated subgroups, so is quite orthogonal to the previous question on finite subquotients.

Comment: ... and conjecture 2 could be restated in a more robust way as "*Every simple subquotient of $F$ is cyclic or isomorphic to $F'$.*" (which technically is a bit stronger since one could imagine a subgroup with another simple quotient, but not part of any composition series).

Comment: As a particular instance of a subgroup, one has the subgroup $F_4$ of elements with only slopes powers of $4$. Its derived subgroup $F'_4$ might be an infinite simple subgroup of $F$ not isomorphic to $F'$.

Comment: There is a conjecture (still open) by Guba and myself that every simple subgroup of $F $ is isomorphic to $F_n'$ for some $n$. Your conjecture 1 with $F $ replaced by $F_n $ is stronger than our conjecture. I do not know (seems unlikely) if all these derived subgroups are isomorphic.